# Why do metaclass have a type?

Tags: python, oop

I've little bit test to fully understand metaclass in python.

```
class Test(object):
    pass


print Test.__class__
print Test.__class__.__class__
print Test.__class__.__class__.__class__
```

All of result is same `type`. but each of their address is not same
I can't really understand why metaclass has a metaclass recursively.
Explain me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, addresses are the same:

```
>>> id(Test.__class__)
6384576
>>> id(Test.__class__.__class__)
6384576
>>> id(Test.__class__.__class__.__class__)
6384576
```

Everything is an object in Python, and each object must have a class (it should belong to some type).  You can access that class/type reference by `__class__` attribute, e.g.:

```
>>> (1).__class__
<type 'int'>
```

Everything includes classes itself, which are of class/type called `type`:

```
>>> (1).__class__.__class__
<type 'type'>
```

In the same time `type 'type'>` is also an object and should reference to some class/type.  But since this is kind of special object, its `__class__` attribute refers to itself:

```
>>> (1).__class__.__class__.__class__ is (1).__class__.__class__
True
```

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood their address is not same.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `Test.__class__`, you get back the type of `Test`, which is `type` (because `Test` is a class identifier).

`type` itself is again a class identifier, so you can call `__class__` (which is inherited from `object`) on it and you get back that its type is, again, `type` because it is a class identifier.

Because you will always get back `type` which is a class itself, you can do this infinitely many times and will always get back that the current object's type is `type`.

Answer (score 0):

All classes are classes which means they are derived from a class called class...

Answer (score 0):

All the python's class object is build by the built-in function type(). You could also try this.

```
>>> T.__class__ == type
True
>>> type(type)
<type 'type'>
```

The T.**class** is equal to the build-in function type which is also an object implemented the **call** function. It's a attribute will be interpret as **class**(T). As your T class have no base class so type() is used which will return the type object.

You could check the python doc about [customizing class creation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) to get detail about class creation.

To determining the appropriate metaclass

- if no bases and no explicit metaclass are given, then type() is used
- if an explicit metaclass is given and it is not an instance of type(), then it is used directly as the metaclass
- if an instance of type() is given as the explicit metaclass, or bases are defined, then the most derived metaclass is used